# Reference an Attribute values from other documents?

Tags: asciidoc

I am exploring AsciiDoc as a replacement for Atlassian Confluence, for our developers to maintain documentation with the code.

One feature I'm missing from Confluence is [Page Properties Report](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/page-properties-report-macro-186089616.html) which  can list pages and the values of properties on those pages.

**I am wondering if there is a strategy to achieve something similar with AsciiDoc?**

I do not need a full automated solution.

I thought if there was a way I could reference the value of an attribute from another document, then I can manually create a table listing of documents, with columns that I manually populate with reference to document attributes.  But I have not been able to find if that's possible.

The following does not work, but is just to illustrate the desired goal for producing a table listing of Architecture Decision Records (ADRs) that displays the attributes of each ADR document.

```
|===
|Decision|Status|Decision date|Amends|Amended by

|xref:adr-1.adoc[ADR 1: Decision Foo]
|{adr-1.adoc:adr-status}
|{adr-1.adoc:adr-date}
|{adr-1.adoc:adr-amends}
|{adr-1.adoc:adr-amendedby}

|xref:adr-2.adoc[ADR 2: Decision Bar]
|{adr-2.adoc:adr-status}
|{adr-2.adoc:adr-date}
|{adr-2.adoc:adr-amends}
|{adr-2.adoc:adr-amendedby}

|===
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `attributes.adoc`, and then include that file in each Asciidoc file that needs the attribute definitions. Once included, the included file's attributes behave as if they had been defined at the location of the `include` macro.

If you need the capability of "plucking" an attribute definition from another file, you could write an extension that implements a macro to achieve that. Be aware that this could be complex to write as you'd have to parse the document and follow any of its `include` macros to learn about all of the attributes defined. And attributes can be redefined as parsing progresses through a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with an additional tool. The tool works on `*.adoc.jam` files and generates the `*.adoc` files. The tool

https://github.com/verhas/jamal

is a general-purpose text macro processor. It is even integrated into Asciidoctor, so you can use it like it was native Asciidoc when editing a file in IntelliJ. (Should also work with other Asciidoctor versions that can handle extensions, but was not tested.)

To automatically get a list of files the snippet macro package contains the `listDir` macro. You have a lot of different filtering and formatting options.

DISCLAIMER: I created Jamal, it is my love child. It is not bragging, it is enforced by Stackoverflow.